# Adding comboboxes with a function to be called by a buttonpress

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

So my problem is that I want to add comboboxes to a windows forms based program by clicking on a button. What I have now is:

```
private void addCoworkerBox()
    {
        DDLList.Add(new ComboBox());
        comboBoxInit(coworkerIndex);
        coworkerIndex++;
    }
```

and:

```
private void comboBoxInit(int i)
    {
        var yValue = DDLCoworker.Location.Y;
        DDLList[i].DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        DDLList[i].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10F);
        DDLList[i].FormattingEnabled = true;
        yValue += 34;
        DDLList[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(380, yValue);
        DDLList[i].Name = "comboBox";
        DDLList[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 28);
        DDLList[i].TabIndex = 2;
        DDLList[i].Items.AddRange(names.ToArray());
        DDLList[i].Show();
    }
```

the list `DLLList`, the int `yValue` and the int `coworkerindex` are initialized further up in my code.

I know that this is kind of a repost, but the answers to the others don't seem to help me.

The above code does not work. When I press the button that should add the new combobox, nothing happens. I have added a function for said button, that calls the `addCoworkerBox()` function.

Comment: So what's your question? Does this code not work how you want it to? Why not?

Comment: "When I press the button" which Button? the one in the newly created `ComboBox`?

Comment: @stuartd Oh sorry for the unclarity of my question. I just edited it to where the last part of my question specifies that my code doesn't work.

Comment: @MindSwipe And to you, sorry for the unclarity. Just clarified it in my post! I was talking about the button that calls the function `addCoworkerBox()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created it just fine, but you've not added it to the form.  There's a collection of controls - you need to add it to that...

```
Controls.Add(DDLList[i]);
```

Comment: Oh wow.. such a small thing. Thanks man! You're a lifesaver. My boss is kinda breathing down my neck to get this done xD

Comment: Haha - tell him to chill and show him that it works :D  Happy to help.